# Vim regex to find replace tabs on the line after match

Tags: regex, unreal-engine4, visual-studio-2019

I'm writing some macros to speed up Unreal Engine development, it has some code that doesn't work with VS2019 auto-formatting.

I use VIM inside the IDE so I'm trying to write a macro to fix the auto editing errors:

```cpp
class SECONDPROJECT_API URobotAnimInstance : public UAnimInstance
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = AnimationProperties)
      void UpdateAnimationProperties();
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Movement)
      class AMain* Main;
};
```

The UFUNCTION / UPROPERTY are known as macros, they insert code from elsewhere in the project, which the IDE doesn't understand and causes the next line to be indented.

I need a regex search and replace command that finds these keywords:
UCLASS|UINTERFACE|USTRUCT|UFUNCTION|UPROPERTY|GENERATED_BODY

And then removes the first tab on the next line if there is one, but I'm really struggling to figure out how to do that with regex.

Comment: Can you put semicolons after the macros? That'd probably make the auto formatter happy

Comment: `I use VIM inside the IDE` it is something like a vim-like plugin of your IDE or it is a real vim, which has the full power of vim?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Nah that's the problem, you can't.

Comment: @Kent It's an extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JaredParMSFT.VsVim

Really fantastic it works great. I use it for all the editing and then UE4 has something called live coding which can recompile while the game is still running!

Comment: @JackClayton ok, then I removed vim tag because it is not a vim problem. It's an easy job for the real vim. But no idea with the vim extension.

Comment: @Kent Vim find and replace works the same with the VS2019 extension. All good I'm using a preview version of and Idea product now that does all the formatting.

Comment: @JackClayton I don't know the VS2019, so I cannot tell if vim's find and replace works the same with it. But I doubt it.e.g. does vs2019 support \zs \ze \%V \%# or the s command `s/pattern/\=vimfunction()/` ?

Comment: Hi sorry Kent, I've stopped using VS2019, it really had a lot of deep issues with Unreal Engine. I've discovered a new IntelliJ product that's in preview called Rider which is purpose built for Unreal Engine, working perfectly for me. VsVim does support all of those commands yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started using a preview version of IntelliJ Rider for Unreal Engine, which takes care of all these formatting issues.